# Xtb broker socket connection

Tags: websocket, stream-socket-client

Hello I'm trying to connect to websocket connection shared by xtb stock broker.

The documentation is here: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/2.5.0

There is mentioned: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/2.5.0#communication-with-the-xstation-api that I should use port 5113 and use host xapi.xtb.com for real account and streaming data.

That's why I create URI like below (wss is because SSL connection):

wss://xapi.xtb.com:5113

I'm not able to connect:
[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xapi.xtb.com` is not for `websocket` communication. They have another links in their documentation for `websocket`s:

```
wss://ws.xtb.com/demo

wss://ws.xtb.com/demoStream

wss://ws.xtb.com/real

wss://ws.xtb.com/realStream
```